#  No overload for method 'Write' takes 0 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

what's wrong with that code ? I'm getting the error from this topic's title.

```
@{ var errors = ViewData.ModelState.Values.Where(x=>x.Errors.Count > 0).ToList();}
```

**SOLVED**, look @ the comments

Comment: Are you sure that's the exact line where the error is happening?

Comment: This code is correct and should not produce the error that you are seeing. Can you provide the code that surrounds this snippet? Maybe the line number reporting is not working correctly.

Comment: Ok, I've solved the problem. I had to move that line outside the `@using (Html.BeginForm()){ }`

Comment: No, you don't have to move that line outside your `using` block.  See my answer.

Comment: Please do not put tags in the title.

Answer (score 20):

Inside a `using` statement or other code block, Razor expects code, not markup.
Therefore, you must put in code directly, not in `@{ ... }` blocks.

The Razor parser interprets your code as `@` (printing an empty expression), followed by a normal C#  statement block (`{ ... }`).

You only use `@{ ... }` blocks to put code where Razor is expecting *markup*.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  In my case, I had a `@{ Html.RenderPartial(...) }` inside my `@using (Html.BeginForm())`.  It worked when I changed it to `@Html.Partial(...)` without the curly braces.